# Make grunt run a task after subtask is done

Tags: javascript, protractor, gruntjs

## Problem

I have a grunt task to start automated tests. The logic is as follows:

clean `.tmp` folder -> find needed data file in .xlx format -> convert the file in JSON under `.tmp` folder -> start tests against converted files

It was working fine, until the data file became very big in size, and tests start before the subtask that converts the file finishes

## Question

How do I make grunt wait until the subtask is done, no more/no less?

## What I've tried so far

I've tried several ways making `convert-data-sheet` task asynchronous without any luck.

**1.** Obviously the first thing I've tried was this

```
// register task for converting data sheet
grunt.registerTask('convert-data-sheet', 'task for converting xslx file into json', function(product, tenant, environment, codeBase) {
    
   let done = this.async();
   /*
    Some code here, not essential to the question
    */
    // run conversion for each sheet
    for (let i = 0; i < sheetTabs.length; i++) {
        dst = path.resolve(__dirname, './protractor/.tmp_files/test_data', `${sheetTabs[i]}.json`);
        options.sheet = (i + 1).toString();
        convertExcel(src, dst, options);
    }
    done();
});

// register a task for ui tests
grunt.registerTask('e2e', 'task for protractor tests', function() {
    let done = this.async();
    grunt.initConfig({
        /**
         * Long and boring initConfig object
         */
    });

    // clean .tmp directory
    grunt.task.run('clean:tmpFiles');

    // generate data json files and other files
    grunt.task.run([`convert-data-sheet:${parameters.product}:${parameters.tenant}:${parameters.environment}:${parameters.codeBase}`, 'bake:protractorConfigs']);

    grunt.task.run('protractor:configFile');
    done();
});
```

It still tries to run Protractor before the data files created

**2.** Here is my current code that just hangs for specified period of time

```
// register task for converting data sheet
grunt.registerTask('convert-data-sheet', 'task for converting xslx file into json', function(product, tenant, environment, codeBase) {
    /*
    Some code here, not essential to the question
    */
    // run conversion for each sheet
    for (let i = 0; i < sheetTabs.length; i++) {
        dst = path.resolve(__dirname, './protractor/.tmp_files/test_data', `${sheetTabs[i]}.json`);
        options.sheet = (i + 1).toString();
        convertExcel(src, dst, options);
    }
});

// register a task for ui tests
grunt.registerTask('e2e', 'task for protractor tests', function() {

    let done = this.async();

    grunt.initConfig({
        /**
         * Long and boring initConfig object
         */
    });

    // clean .tmp directory
    grunt.task.run('clean:tmpFiles');

    // generate data json files and other files
    grunt.task.run([`convert-data-sheet:${parameters.product}:${parameters.tenant}:${parameters.environment}:${parameters.codeBase}`, 'bake:protractorConfigs']);

    // run protractor with a delay 2000ms to let previous tasks finish
    setTimeout(function() {
        grunt.task.run('protractor:configFile');
        done();
    }, 2000);
});
```

But it turns out that even the current code is not doing what is expected. It just hangs for 2 sec not doing ANYTHING, EVEN BEFORE the data conversion started. So from logs I see - grunt started -> hang 2000 -> convert -> run protractor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

```
// register task for converting data sheet
grunt.registerTask('convert-data-sheet', 'task for converting xslx file into json', function(product, tenant, environment, codeBase) {

   let done = this.async();
   /*
    Some code here, not essential to the question
    */
    mkdirp(path.resolve(__dirname, './protractor/.tmp_files/test_data'), function(err) {

        // run conversion for each sheet
        for (let i = 0; i < sheetTabs.length; i++) {
            dst = path.resolve(__dirname, './protractor/.tmp_files/test_data', `${sheetTabs[i]}.json`);
            options.sheet = (i + 1).toString();
            convertExcel(src, dst, options,
                (err, data) => {
                    if (i === (sheetTabs.length - 1)) {
                        done();
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });
});

// register a task for ui tests
grunt.registerTask('e2e', 'task for protractor tests', function() {

    grunt.initConfig({
        /**
         * Long and boring initConfig object
         */
    });

    // clean .tmp directory
    grunt.task.run('clean:tmpFiles');

    // generate data json files and other files
    grunt.task.run([`convert-data-sheet:${parameters.product}:${parameters.tenant}:${parameters.environment}:${parameters.codeBase}`, 'bake:protractorConfigs']);

    grunt.task.run('protractor:configFile');

});
```

## What's special about this approach

I didn't completely understand what was going on with sync execution of the task.

As we all know this scenario

```
console.log(1)
setTimeout(function(){console.log(2)}, 1000)
console.log(3)
```

results in

```
1
3
2
```

because JS just schedules the `setTimeout` and while it waits for `1000` ms, it carries on with the script

In my case you can think of `convertExcel` as of `setTimeout`. So JS scheduled conversion and then immediately invoked `done()`, so Grunt didn't wait until the process is actually done.

Luckily, `excel-as-json` module has option for passing a callback function which I did. So all I need to do is to call `done()` when the conversion of last sheet's tab was actually done.

The only problem that I encountered after the fix was this error `Fatal error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir ...` which was solved by just bringing `mkdir` into the play

## Important

It's still not ideal, because if I have 10 sheets in my excel file, and the fifth one is the biggest, but I'm waiting only for the last one, it won't work. But as long as I know how to fix it I will do so if needed

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest what you need is to have Semaphore Variable

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)

In this case create global variable called `dataLoaded` and set it to `false`.

In your first sub task set this to `true` once it has completed.

Your second task can then check the value of `dataLoaded` when it starts and if it is not set to `true`, call `setTimeout` on itself to wait a bit and try again.

```
function foo() {
  if (!dataLoaded) {
    setTimeout(foo, 50)
    return
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Good approach, those three dots represent the code that should start tests? or that code should go outside of the function?

Comment: Code to start the tests